# Powershell - removing drive letter from sqlcmd variable

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am having issues when running 'sqlcmd' from within Powershell, with passing a variable(-v and a folder path).  Powershell is stripping the 'C' from the path.  Here is the command:

```
 $CommandLine = "sqlcmd -v dataFeedDir=" + """$ssisDataFeeds""" + " -U user -P password -S " + $Env:COMPUTERNAME + " -i " +  "`"" + $setLoc + "\SQL Scripts\Set_SSIS_DataFeed_Directory.sql" + "`"" + " -o " + "`"" + $setLoc + "\SQL Scripts\Set_SSIS_DataFeed_Directory.log" + "`""
```

If I print the command, I get:

```
sqlcmd -v dataFeedDir="C:\is_data_feeds" -U user -P password -S myhost -i "C:\Automation\6_0_0\TruCareInstaller\SQL Scripts\Set_SSIS_DataFeed_Directory.sql" -o "C:\Automation\6_0_0\TruCareInstaller\SQL Scripts\Set_SSIS_DataFeed_Directory.log"
```

If I paste the above in the cmd prompt and run it, it works fine.

The error I'm getting from Powershell is:

```
     Sqlcmd: ':\is_data_feeds': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
At :line:1 char:2  
+ &  <<<< sqlcmd -v dataFeedDir="C:\is_data_feeds" -U user -P password -S myhost -i "C:\Automation\6_0_0\TruCareInstaller\SQL Scripts\Set_SSIS_DataFeed_Directory.sql" -o "C:\Automation\6_0_0\TruCareInstaller\SQL Scripts\Set_SSIS_DataFeed_Directory.log"
```

I found some other post about this, but the solution did not work.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue after trying MANY things.

I used this to deal with the quote issues:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe"  "/k $CommandLine"
```